# GlassFish does not support to share a common ClassLoader among EARs? Is there a workaround?

Tags: glassfish-3, porting, jboss-eap-4.3.x

Trying to discover if it's feasible to attempt tackling blocking issues associated with porting JFire ERP, (EJB 3.1 compliant) from Jboss 4, to Glassfish v3.

I'd like to deploy JFire ERP on glassfish v3 instead of jboss, so I can integrate it with the systems I've already developed & deployed on gf. 
In the documentation they describe this 'sharing a common ClassLoader' as a blocking issue. But the quoted sun document is outdated.

"According to this Sun document (Sun GlassFish Communications Server 1.5 Developer's Guide), GlassFish does not support to share a common ClassLoader among EARs. Since JFire uses EARs on the server side to organize modules (one EAR = one module), this is a blocking issue."

I have done some research into it, but I don’t really understand the problem or even if it still is an issue in gf v3.

I’d really just like some insight into the issue & maybe a tip as to where I should be looking. Any direction or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor detail, but the documentation referenced is not the correct one. Try http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/coll/1343.13 instead (latest GlassFish stable release if 3.0.1).

Also not sure what you mean by EJB 3.1 compliant - this is a technology release a year ago and not yet supported by JBoss. If it is indeed based on EJB 3.1, then JNDI deploy names have now been standardized and the GlassFish issue referenced on the jfire site is moot.

I think you need some collaboration/changes from the jfire folks.